# Unable to get Ubuntu 12.04 to start on Acer 5000, it seems to install alright

Tags: 12.04

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 on my Acer 5000 laptop I 
restart it and it says running Ubuntu for the first time and it only gets so far 
and the screen blinks between different screens like it can only get so far then it 
does not know what to do? It is running fine with Windows XP, no errors. In windows
 system it says AMD Turion 64 Mobile, Technology ML-30, 1.6GHZ 448MB Ram, Physical 
Address Extension. Could the AMD system or maybe not enough Ram be a problem? It has
 enough Ram for Windows XP to run and I did not want to get any more ram until Ubuntu
 runs on it.
   While it is trying to run Ubuntu after it is installed the screen shows I/O errors
 then it looks to be installing and uninstalling parts. Maybe something is resisting
 it like the AMD system? I am hoping someone can help and or possibly someone who
 ran into this type problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if  you are trying to dual boot, is that right?
Did you use WUBI to install Ubuntu?  You really need to.
You can download it from Ubuntu here and also read the 
instructions on how to you it first.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

Oh, and delete your old Ubuntu installation first!

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying without success to get ubuntu to completely boot up to where it will run. When booting right away from the install CD there are multiple "Buffer i/o error on device Zram Logical Block" and just before it stops one of the ending sayings is Starting load fallback graphics (Fail). Does that mean ubuntu does not know what to install to make the display adapter work? In XP the display adapter is listed as SIS-M7606x. How to get or direct the ubuntu to put the correct driver in I do not know. My goal was to get a dual boot Win XP Pro and ubuntu. I tried installing with Wubi and that does not work either, keeps stopping flashing between screens. The wubi install is a 64 tar, that is what the installer gives me. Should it be a 32 Tar being that XP is 32 bit?
   If I could erase Windows and just install Ubuntu that will be OK but am afraid that if I erase windows will have to reinstall it, if Ubuntu keeps refusing to run. Windows runs great without any problems.